# What is the purpose of slug for wagtail root page

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

My `urls.py` file as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'),name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path('info/', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

It is a fresh integration of Wagtail into Existing Django. So, I have only 1 SITE on wagtail admin portal which is the default one `localhost:80` with `ROOT PAGE` pointing to default root page `Welcome to Wagtail`.
[image]
below screenshot shows that ROOT PAGE has `slug = home`.
[image]

I can successfully access the root page via `domain.com/info` as per the settings in `urls.py`. But I got `404 Page not found` for both `domain.com/info/home` and `domain.com/home`. It seems to me that `slug` is completely useless for ROOT Page.
Above testing makes me wondering whether `slug` setting is cosmetic for ROOT PAGE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of slug on the root page in Wagtail is nothing. The root of a website is `/`. The slug field of the root page is ignored.

The slug is automatically populated and doesn't do any harm.

In Wagtail *any* page in the page tree can be selected as the `Site.root_page`. This can be convenient in multi-site setups. A subpage of one site might be the root_page/homepage of another site. Then the slug doesn't have a purpose in one site, but *does* have a purpose on another site.